Delete 2-line paragraphs, keep 3-line paragraphs, maintain newline between all
On a Linux machine with GNU tools I have an ascii file that consists of only 2-line and 3-line paragraphs, each paragraph separated by a newline. All 2-line paragraphs are to be deleted so that all 3-line paragraphs remain separated by a newline. I've been experimenting unsuccessfully with awk paragraphs. Original content:
aaa aaaaaa
bb bbb 
cc cccc ccccc cccc

ddd d
e eeeeee ee

fff ff
ggg gggg gggg
hhh hhh hh hhhh

ii
jjjj jjjj jjjjjj j jjj

The above should look like this:
aaa aaaaaa
bb bbb 
cc cccc ccccc cccc

fff ff
ggg gggg gggg
hhh hhh hh hhhh

I would prefer sed, awk, or perl for this.

please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) results generated by said code

Google awk paragraph mode as a starting point.

I've been experimenting with awk -v R strings and the use of the newlines as delimiters. I hope to learn more about that.

You can use perl for this (along with several other possibilities)
perl -n -00 -e 'chomp; print "$_\n\n" unless y/\n// == 1' datafile

Or expanded out somewhat,
perl -n -00 -e '
    # -n -00 = while { } loop reading a paragraph at a time
    # -e = execute the following code in the loop
    chomp;                                # Discard trailing newline (if any)
    print "$_\n\n" unless y/\n// == 1;    # Output paragraphs unless they have just 1 newline
' datafile

Result from your example data:
aaa aaaaaa
bb bbb
cc cccc ccccc cccc

fff ff
ggg gggg gggg
hhh hhh hh hhhh


With GNU awk:
awk 'BEGIN{FS=RS; RS=""} NF==3{print; print ""}' file

Output:

aaa aaaaaa
bb bbb 
cc cccc ccccc cccc

fff ff
ggg gggg gggg
hhh hhh hh hhhh


Output contains one trailing empty line.
See: 8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR

You should use ORS rather than the extra prints, especially with that link. And you can set the variables on the command line: gawk -vRS='\n\n' -vORS='\n\n' -vFS='\n' 'NF == 3' test.in or gawk 'NF == 3' FS="\n" RS="\n\n" ORS="\n\n" file.

@Kevin: See my comment to a deleted answer.

Using any awk with a blank line at the end of the output:
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v ORS='\n\n' 'NF != 2' file
aaa aaaaaa
bb bbb
cc cccc ccccc cccc

fff ff
ggg gggg gggg
hhh hhh hh hhhh


Using any awk without a blank line at the end of the output:
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' 'NF != 2{print sep $0; sep=ORS}' file
aaa aaaaaa
bb bbb
cc cccc ccccc cccc

fff ff
ggg gggg gggg
hhh hhh hh hhhh


We probably want NF != 2.  The requirements are badly stated. We are to delete all the 2 line paragraphs, which is clear. But then keep the three line ones, which seems like it should be "keep all other paragraphs, but I believe they are all three-lines".

@Kaz on re-reading the question I think you're probably right but I'll leave it as-is for now to see what the OP says about it. There's a good chance the OPs whole input is either 2 or 3 lines in which case either condition will work for them.

Confirming that using NF != 2 in that string seems to be the best awk option for my requirements.

OK, I changed the condition from NF == 3 to NF != 2.
